# More / file reporting "not a text file" file which contains only one letter and newline

Tags: more, util-linux

I am confused by the output of the `more` program under linux. When creating a file which contains only a single letter (except for special letters like `ä` which work fine), more does not report the file's content, but that the file is not a text file. As soon as the file contains more than one letter, `more` does not report an error, but simply prints the file's output.

```bsh
> rm file
> echo 'h' > file
> more file
 
******** file: Not a text file ********
 
> cat file
h
```

Is this a bug in my version of `more` or do specific requirements to text files exist, that are not fulfilled in my one-letter file example?

more version: `more from util-linux 2.36.2`.

### Further details

**Content of the file**
The output of od is as follows:

```bsh
> od -x file
0000000 0a68
0000002
```

From what I understand, the problem does not seem to be only caused by `echo` behaving differently from the way I expected, because when I use printf as it follows, the problem persists and the output of the `od` command is the same (so the files produced via `echo` and `printf` should be the same)

```bsh
> printf 'h\n' > file2
> more file2
 
******** file2: Not a text file ********

> od -x file2
0000000 0a68
0000002
```

**Version of `file` utility**

```
> file --version
file-5.40
magic file from /usr/share/file/misc/magic
seccomp support included
```

**System information**
My system is arch linux, and echo is the shell build-in command which I utilized via bash and zsh.

**Bug report**
Thanks to your feedback I was able to report this as a bug at the correct bug tracker:
https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=256

Comment: What is the output of `hd file` or `od -x file`?

Comment: ox -x file outputs 
`0000000 0a68
0000002`

Comment: I have (long story) several one and two-bytes files on which "more" is called by a script and I never experienced this behaviour. I am now with util-linux 2.34 on Ubuntu 20.04, but this script was deployed on Ubuntu 14 (if not maybe even 12).

Comment: @LSerni On a different system I've also got a script which I now moved to my other system on which I experienced this issue; because `more` outputs the warning instead of the file' s content, my script broke

Comment: Please remember to always mention your operating system and environment. Your `echo` isn't behaving like the common bash builtin, so giving details of your system is essential to better understand the issue.

Comment: One last check. Because in the source code `more` has two ways of finding out if the file is binary or not. What does `file file2` report?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani `file` reports `file: data`, so that might be the error! Is this a bug in the component which determines the file type or is this a misconfiguration of the system on my end?

Comment: @mutableVoid, could be this: https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=180 Not sure though, couldn't test. You could try with `aa\n`, and `ab\n` etc. Though hmm, `ä\n` would still be only two code points. Oh, the UTF-8 detection looks to be separate.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, I think you're right in that it might be related to the fix for this, as the fix seems to be new in the version in which I first encountered this issue (and I checked that the scenario 
described in the bug report works with my version of `file`). Printing two times the same char also causes `file` to report `binary`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in more, but in `libmagic`, that is also used by `file`.

For example, `libmagic` reports that an empty file is binary, and `more` has specific code to deal with that.

I see at least two solutions, you can rebuild `more` from source, without libmagic support or you can downgrade `libmagic`.

By the way, you should report it.

Comment: Could be due to this issue: https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=180 "0000180: A file filled with 0xFF gets reported to be ISO-8859" -> "Fixed by requiring at least 3 distinct character values."